# Is there a way to use wildcard for CSS selectors within html_nodes()?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape reviews off a website using R. I am using CSS Selector Gadget to identify the CSS elements. There is one field "Recommended" that I need help with. If the user has recommended, the CSS selector is ".rating-yes", whereas if the user has not recommended it is ".rating-no". I need the output as "yes/no" under the recommended field. Is there a way to use multiple selectors or wildcard within html_nodes()?

Edit:
Here is a sample code:

```
url <- paste0("https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/delta-air-lines/page/1")
h <- read_html(url)
recommended <- h %>% html_nodes(".rating-yes") %>% html_text()
```

I need to capture both ".rating-yes" and ".rating-no" under "recommended" field.

Comment: It would help to see some example input: either a link to the website or some example HTML/CSS from the site.

Comment: `html_nodes` implements most of the [CSS3 selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/) so you can specify contains, begins with, ends with and so on. But we really need to see input data to help.

Comment: Please share your code and also the url/html in question. Html can be shared using the snippet tool via [edit].